# Model binding complex object via query string to new ASPNET Core Razor Page

Tags: query-string, model-binding, razor-pages

We're talking the NEW Razor pages in ASPNET Core 2.0.

I want to pass a complex object to a Razor Page via the OnGetAsync.  This works fine for flat objects.  For complex objects, I tried passing the same format that works when calling a normal controller:

```
class Child {
   public int Y { get; set; }
   public int Z { get; set; }
}

class Parent {
   public int X { get; set; }
   public Child Me { get; set; }
}
```

I pass a serialized object in the query string (to a controller) as:

```
?X=value&Child[Y]=value&Child[Z]=value
```

That works fine when calling a ASPNET Core 2.0 controller.  But, if I pass this to a new Razor Page, the Parent parameter object is there, but the Child member will be null; the model state will be invalid as well.

Any way to pass a complex object via the query string to a Razor Page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the values of the child properties, you will have to use another approach. If for example you have the following code:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet(Parent parent)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you can pass the data using the following URL format:

```
http://localhost:50050/?parent.Me.Y=4
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pitaridis!  This works very well.  Small tweak was to use: ?Parent.Y=4